Which .crt to use for PKCS12?
I signed up for an unmanaged VPS with A2 Hosting, with a new domain name obtained along with the VPS. As part of the deal, they gave me a free security certificate. I am now trying to use the certificate in the Payara application server, Community Edition. The instructions for configuring Payara to use a security certificate start with the command:
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert.crt -inkey mycert.key -out mycert.p12 -name mydomain_certificate

A2 Hosting provided a number of files that seem to be related to the security certificate. For files with the extensions the command above is looking for, I find one file named mydomain.com.key in /home/user/ssl/private and two files with a .crt extension in /home/user/ssl/cert, named mydomain.com.crt and mydomain.com-ca.crt. My questions are, what might be the difference between those .crt files and which one should I use? The one without "-ca" in the name is slightly larger than the other one.

View the contents to determine which one is the public and which is the private key

You don't need to guess from the file size; if the files have only one certificate each, you can use openssl x509 -in foo.crt -noout -text to inspect them – look at the Issuer and Subject lines. (If they have multiple certs per file, then the GnuTLS tool certtool -i < foo.crt will do the same.)
Most likely you need both – one file is your own certificate while the other is an "intermediate" certificate to complete the chain between the former and the actual root CA.
(All CAs use at least a two-tier model; the root CA is closely guarded and only issues intermediate CA certs, while those intermediate CAs are what actually issues the various server certs.)
The usual practice is that it's the server's job to provide all necessary intermediate certs to the client. So you probably need -in mysite.crt -certfile mysite-ca.crt.

Everything you said makes sense, and I succesfully built the .p12 file using both .crt files. However, after adding the certificates to the keystore and the site-specific one (without the "-ca") to the Trust Store, my Payara installation is toast. I will have to wipe it out, do a reinstall and look for a better set of instructions before I try this again.

Actually, I was able to remove the (bad?) keys/certs from the keystore and the Trust Store and recover my Payara installation to operational status. This whole business seems to be a bit of a black art that requires a professional to actually make it work, though, so I probably won't try again until I've obtained such resources.

The host certificate definitely shouldn't need to go in the Trust Store – it's the store that holds CA certificates, if anything – but it sounds a bit like the custom addition overrode the system-provided trust store making it not trust any HTTPS certificates. Either way, shouldn't need to add anything there.

I was following the instructions here: https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/documentation/payara-server/server-configuration/ssl-certificates.html
I could try just adding the certificate to the keystore and not the Trust Store and see if that makes any difference.
